# Visual Studio ignoring my .obj 3D model files when adding to project/uploading to GitHub

Tags: visual-studio, github

Long story short, I am working on a game like applocation written in C (using OpenGL and SDL2).

I have my main .c file and a bunch of headers and other .c files, a few .txt files for settings, and a folder for textures and a folder for my own made 3D .obj files.

Recently I tried uploading the entire solution to GitHub (I don't have much experience with GitHub), and all went fine, but it didn't upload my .obj files. Everything got uploaded but my models. It uploaded a single .mtl file that I don't use, but not the .obj files I actually use.

I tried adding my files first by clicking on the project and "Add" -> "Existing item", but then they showed up as "ignored" in the solution explorer (except the .mtl file).

So any reason why it ignores my .obj files, when it uploads everything else just fine? I tried uploading my .obj files to GitHub manually in the browser, but then it didn't allow me to push anymore from Visual Studio because if my project being behind the master branch.

Comment: The microsoft compiler (and some other compilers for windows) saves object files created from source files (c, c++ etc), with filenames ending with ".obj". Automatically generated files does typically not make sense for source control management, and very often messes things up. So this is probably a case of github saving people for shooting themselves in the foot. If your 3d models are not automatically generated, then the best thing would be to use a different extension to not confuse them with executable object files.

Comment: Look in your .gitignore file - it's probably ignoring *.obj files.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it! Removed the .obj extension from the gitingnore list and now it pushed without a problem.